# clustering 1column in data frame R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have data frame

```
data1<- read.csv("book1.csv", header= TRUE)

head(data1)
  product    cost
1 Product1    50
2 Product2  1390
3 Product3    50
4 Product4   485
5 Product5   325
6 Product6   515
```

I will make a Clustering for the cost column to get 3 clusters : high , medium , low like :

`high = 500 - 2000` , `medium = 100 - 499` , `Low = 0 - 99`

then I get

```
   product    cost
1 Product1    Low
2 Product2    High
3 Product3    Low
4 Product4   medium 
5 Product5   medium 
6 Product6   high
```

can I do this with `kmeans()` function in R ?

or another way can help ?

Comment: Hey, Reem, what do you want to do with `kmeans`, the clustering? or an analysis after the clustering?

Comment: I want analysis after clustering

Comment: try `?ifelse`, or `?cut`.

Comment: but if I used real data as new data how can classify ?

Comment: @Reem with `ifelse` or `cut`, too. Straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

As you would like to *predefine* the thresholds (and that is better), you **are not doing clustering** (it is "supervised", not learned).

What you ask for is a **simple if-then statement**...

Answer (score 0):

You can also make indexes and match the values. This will require less code and avoid writing nested if-else loops. Say, `df` is your data frame:

```
# generate indexes
i1 <- df$cost %in% seq(0,99)
i2 <- df$cost %in% seq(100,499)
i3 <- df$cost %in% seq(500,2000)

df$cost <- c('Low','medium','High')[i1+2*i2+3*i3]

    product   cost
1: Product1    Low
2: Product2   High
3: Product3    Low
4: Product4 medium
5: Product5 medium
6: Product6   High
```